# Problem with Flutter: SingleChildScrollView - no scrolling

Tags: flutter, scroll, singlechildscrollview

I have a question, in my mini app I wanted to add a SingleChildScrollView widget.
I checked tutorials, guides, stackoverflow, I added Expanded, Column, Container before and nothing - still this function doesn't work as it should - not scrolling

Below is a code snippet - please help because I don't want to pull my hair out of my head anymore ;)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:icon_forest/icon_forest.dart';
import './buttons.dart';
import './containers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 60,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          title: Image.asset(
            'images/logo.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1B1919),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                color: Colors.white),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
                color: Colors.white),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                color: Colors.white),
          ],
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ContainerHomePage('Name1', '20H'),
                ContainerHomePage('Name1', '20H'),
                ContainerHomePage('Name1', '20H'),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                    ButtonChoise('name'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and buttons.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ButtonChoise extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
   ButtonChoise(this.name,{super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        
        child: Text(name),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.black,
          side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
          ),
          minimumSize: Size(120, 30)

        
        ),
        onPressed: () {}, 
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you testing the scroll isnt working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SingleChildScrollView` is scrolling on `horizontal` hope this is what wanted. if not remove or change it to `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,`. But If you are testing on chrome and cant able to drag with mouse, you need to config the `scrollBehavior`. You can wrap the widget with `ScrollConfiguration`, or just call

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  scrollBehavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
    dragDevices: {
      PointerDeviceKind.touch,
      PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working right now. Yes I tested on chrome browser

Comment: Glad help, you can find more about [breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag)